# Trigger a Workflow only when Particular column is updated in a library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

How to Trigger a workflow only when a column is updated. I have a column called "Comments History", when anyone adds a new comment then workflow should Trigger

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid the only way is an ugly one (as often with workflows):

- Add a second column (and make it hidden) on the list to store the previous value of the comments field (let's say "Previous Comments History")
- When the workflow starts, make it compare the value of both columns "Comments History" and "Previous Comments History".
- If they're the same: copy value from "Comments History" to "Previous Comments History" and end the WF .
- If they differ: copy value from "Comments History" to "Previous Comments History" and do what you want.

Set your WF to start on any update of the item.